# Conflicting type for function error

Tags: c, function, implicit-declaration

This is my first C program and I don't know why I get the error below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    struct ListNode* next;
   int content;
} ListNode;

int main() {
    //puts("Hello UPC World"); /* prints Hello UPC World */

    //ListNode* h = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    gridinit(3, 5);
    //int c = h->content;
    //printf("%d",c);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

ListNode* gridinit(int numcolumns, int numrows) {
    ListNode* head = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    head->content = 2;
    head->next = NULL;
    return head;
}
```

Why do I get an error saying

> type conflict in func gridinit()

Comment: Your are returning a node from function but why are you not assigning it to a variable where gridinit is called.

Comment: it looks like you need forward declaration

add this line before the main fuction:
`ListNode *gridinit( int numcolumns, int numrows );`

Comment: Please indent your code

Answer (score 2):

Define your function declaration at the top of your struct

```
ListNode* gridinit(int numcolumns, int numrows);

typedef struct {
    struct ListNode* next;
   int content;
} ListNode;

 int main() {
//puts("Hello UPC World"); /* prints Hello UPC World */

//ListNode* h = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
gridinit(3, 5);
//int c = h->content;
//printf("%d",c);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

ListNode* gridinit(int numcolumns, int numrows) {
ListNode* head = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
head->content = 2;
head->next = NULL;
return head;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because your function is defined *after* it is called.  You can declare a prototype of the function just after your `struct` and before `main` as

```
ListNode* gridinit(int numcolumns, int numrows);
```

and you will be good for compile.

Answer (score 2):

Add a [forward declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration#Examples) for `gridinit()` and [everything works fine](http://ideone.com/ekIWCv):

```
...

typedef struct {
    struct ListNode* next;
   int content;
} ListNode;

// Declare the gridinit function
ListNode* gridinit(int, int);

...
```

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** answer - For all the functions which are used (*called*) before they are defined, you need to add a [forward declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) for those functions before the caller function. In this case, as the definition of `gridinit()` is written after `main()` and `main()` uses `gridinit()` you have to add the forward declaration of `gridinit()` before `main()` and you'll be good to go.

To elaborate the case, in your `main()` function, you're calling `gridinit()`, but till that point, compiler has no idea about the prototype of the `gridinit()` function.

Due to backward compatibility, a feature called *implicit declaration* of a function *assumes* that a function, which has been used before it is defined or declared, accepts any number of parameters and returns an `int`.

Later, when you're actually defining the function, you're making the return type as `ListNode*`, which is creating the conflict here.

FWIW, as per the `C99` standard (onwards), the (*evil*) feature of *implicit function declaration* has been officially removed but compilers still continue to support the same for legacy code. If you enable compiler warnings and compile with strict conformance, you should get warned (or even stopped) by your compiler, in case, a forward declaration is missing.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a declaration or definition of `gridinit` before it is called in `main` (the compiler needs to know it exists).

Also, you should not ignore the return value of `gridinit`, which returns a pointer you have allocated memory for (ignoring it would therefore cause a memory leak), instead you should assign it to `h` without allocating memory in `main` (because you're doing that already in `gridinit`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    struct ListNode* next;
    int content;
} ListNode;

ListNode* gridinit(int numcolumns, int numrows) {

int main() {
    //puts("Hello UPC World"); /* prints Hello UPC World */

    ListNode* h = gridinit(3, 5);
    int c = h->content;
    printf("%d",c);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

ListNode* gridinit(int numcolumns, int numrows) {
    ListNode* head = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    head->content = 2;
    head->next = NULL;
    return head;
}
```